# Making input element and captcha inline ( in one line) in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form group which consists of a label, a captcha image and an input for that captcha.
The thing I want is to make label at the top of the form group, then the captcha and input stick together in one line. I have done the first item but the other not.

My **HTML**:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="captcha">کد تصادفی</label>
    <div class="input-group">
    <?php echo $captcha; ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" maxlength="4" name="captcha" placeholder="کد تصادفی">
        </div>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('captcha'); ?></span>
</div>
```

**Image**:
[image]

So what should I do?

Comment: The captcha image and input is already in one line, see http://jsfiddle.net/sGqse/1/. Please show also your CSS.

Comment: @OlafDietsche, I haven't changed the css. its the default bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Forms - Basic example](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

> Individual form controls automatically receive some global styling. All textual <input>, <textarea>, and <select> elements with .form-control are set to width: 100%; by default.

When you remove the class `form-control` from the `input`, both elements stay on the same line

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="captcha">کد تصادفی</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <img class="captcha-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/20"/>
        <input type="text" id="captcha" maxlength="4" name="captcha" placeholder="کد تصادفی" />
        </div>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('captcha'); ?></span>
</div>
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGqse/3/)

*Update:*

It took some time fiddling, but here it is. When you add `class="row"` to the outer div and wrap the captcha image and the input in a div and add `class="col-xs-2"` or `class="col-xs-4"` respectively, you get

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
    <label for="captcha">کد تصادفی</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/20" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" maxlength="4" name="captcha" placeholder="کد تصادفی" />
        </div>
    </div> <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('captcha'); ?></span>

</div>
```

Modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGqse/10/)

Comment: OK,But it wouldn't have the effects of bootstrap form elements.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

add css for your input tag:

```
#captcha { display:inline; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the width of the outer container is not large enough for two elements stay inline. The se elements can be limited by a 45% width each.

You can add a border to the outer container `div.form-group`, then you should see what happened.

```
<div class="form-group has-error" style="width:200px;border:1px solid red">
    <label for="captcha">کد تصادفی</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <img class="captcha-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/20"/ style="width:40%">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" maxlength="4" name="captcha" placeholder="کد تصادفی" style="width:40%"/>
        </div>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo form_error('captcha'); ?></span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sGqse/9/